# Redirecting Wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a new WP site, let's called it thenewblog.com.  I also have an old WP site located at theoldblog.com/blog.

The old site has been moved to the new site, however Google has indexed a ton of 'comment pages' in the format theoldblog.com/blog/article/comment-page-x.  Is there a way to redirect those to thenewblog.com/article ?

I am using the Redirection plugin with wildcard, but I don't seem to be able to find a solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What I am looking for is a "bulk" solution, as I know I can redirect each individual page.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your URLs are genuinely of the form `myblog.com/blog/<article-slug>` for articles and `myblog.com/blog/<article-slug>/<comment-page-id>` for comments, you can use a simple [Apache URL rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) in your `.htaccess file`.

Place the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/comment-page-[0-9]+$ /blog/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

That basically says, when the URL matches these 3 rules:

1. **Starts with** `blog/`
2. Has **something** followed by another `/` (our article slug)
3. Has "comment-page-" followed by a number at the end of the URL

Then redirect to `/blog/` with whatever number 2 was from above, so here's an example:

**Input URL:**
`blog/my-article-slug/comment-page-27381`

**Output URL:**
`blog/my-article-slug`

Comment: In his case the correct rewrite rule should be `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/.*$ /blog/$1 [R=301,QSA]`

Comment: I agree about `R=301`, but `.*` at the end is a very broad match when he's only looking for comment IDs.

Comment: The comment pages links in wordpress are in the form of `<post-name>/comment-page-<page-number>` so you should at least do `comment-page-[0-9]+`.

Comment: Just to note, this plugin is great for redirects:
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/